# AWS Lambda - install Python dependencies from a private repository using CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a CDK stack with some lambda Python function. That function depends on a package from a private nexus repository. I can't figure out how I can pass the necessary credentials (username and password) to CDK so that it can download the dependency.

The `PythonFunction` from CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha/README.html#packaging) respects any `requirements.txt`, `Pipfile.lock` or `poetry.lock` files and installs those dependencies. So my first attempt was to retrieve the credentials from AWS Secrets Manager and passing those to `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` using the bundling parameter, like so:

```py
python.PythonFunction(self, "function",
    entry=entry,
    runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    bundling=python.BundlingOptions(
        build_args={"PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL": f"https://{username}:{password}@your.extra-index.url/simple/"}
    )
)
```

but I'm unsure whether this is a secure way. I would need to 'unpack' the secret to clear text which I is strongly advised against by the documentation:

> To make sure secret values don't accidentally end up in readable parts of your infrastructure definition (such as the environment variables of an AWS Lambda Function, where everyone who can read the function definition has access to the secret), using secret values directly is not allowed. You must pass them to constructs that accept SecretValue properties, which are guaranteed to use the value only in CloudFormation properties that are write-only.
>
> *From: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.SecretValue.html*

Anyone any idea on how to get those private dependencies into my Lambda function?